# Remove selected value from dropdowns asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

how to remove selected value from drop downs.

here is my code.

```
@viewbag.empskil = new selectlist(db.skils,"skillid","skillname");
```

my view code

```
@html.Dropdown("skill", @viewbag.empskil as  SelectList);
```

It Showing all skill in drop down An Employee can Have multiple Skill.
multiple skill are adding with rating .

I just Want to remove Already Selected Skill From Drop down.
can anybody tell me how to accomplish this

here is the screen

[image]

I just want if employee having skill these skill will not show in drop down.can any body tell me how it will be done.

Comment: structure of class skill and employee would be usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you will need both server-side and client-side code.  Server-side, take a list of all skills and a list of employee skills and create a new list using LINQs "Except", something like:

```
var unusedSkills = db.skils.ToList().Except(db.empSkils);
@viewbag.empskil = new selectlist(unusedSkills,"skillid","skillname");
```

Client-side, you'll want to use jQuery to remove a skill from the list after it is selected and add it to the employee's list, something like:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this var empskill = db.Skills.Where(m => m.CompanyId == CompanyId).Except(employee.skills); but it give me error System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Comment: without knowing what employee.skills and db.Skills look like, can't help much.  Edit your question and add code details.

Comment: employee have many to many relationship with skill.so employee.skills geting the skills which is attached with employee.

Comment: found the error this is working code var empskill = db.Skills.Where(m => m.CompanyId == CompanyId).tolist().Except(employee.skills) Many thanks